# Getting Response 404 while posting JSON payload to POST Rest API

Tags: json, post, mule, payload, mule-esb

I'm trying to post a JSON payload to a Public POST Rest API in MuleESB but I'm getting this error:

***org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 404 mapped as failure.***

I'm able to call the API with JSON body via Postman Chrome App, but not via Postman Desktop App or MuleESB. I've Google-ing around in the past 2 days but still have no clue what I'm missing. Please enlighten me if you have a clue what caused this not to work.

This is the JSON payload:

```
{
  "username": "dummy",
  "email": "dummy@dummy.com",
  "firstName": "dummy",
  "lastName": "dummy"
}
```

Here's the snippet of my MuleESB code (I'm using 3.8.3):

```
        <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="api.domain.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" responseTimeout="180000" tlsContext-ref="TLS_TrustStore"/>
        <tls:context name="TLS_TrustStore" doc:name="TLS">
            <tls:trust-store path="cacerts.jks" password="pwd"/>
        </tls:context>
        ...
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="c77537ba-aaf3-4497-9f09-06792d1f7556">
        <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java"/>
        <dw:input-variable doc:sample="sample_data\UserDefined.dwl" variableName="userData"/>
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    username: flowVars.username as :string,
    email: flowVars.email as :string,
    firstName: flowVars.firstName as :string,
    lastName: flowVars.lastName as :string
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="payload:#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>        
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>        
        <until-successful maxRetries="3" doc:name="Until Successful" synchronous="true">
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api/1/users" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
                <http:request-builder>
                    <http:header headerName="Authorization" value="abcdefg"/>
                </http:request-builder>
            </http:request>
        </until-successful>
```

Comment: I think you need to attach you http:requester-config with this xml flow and tell us what URL you are trying to hit. (i.e. 404 should mean that you are hitting an incorrect address, the path is computed by computing the base address/path in the http:requester-config + the path used in the http:request message processor)

Comment: Hi @AndréSchembri, added HTTP Request Config per your request. The path that I'm trying to access is https://api.domain.com/api/1/users.

Comment: I'm doing Mule development in my VM and found out Postman in my VM is throwing this error too, but Postman in my local machine is not. What could be possibly go wrong with VM? What and how can I check?

Comment: What do you mean Postman in your VM / local machine? A Virtualbox or similar kind of VM, a Cloud-based VM ? 
Maybe your VM internet connection is not properly configured, thus it cannot access the URL you configured. Are you testing your app on your local machine or the VM ?

Comment: Hi @PierreB. sorry, let me clarify. I'm doing Mule development in my VM and found out Postman Desktop in my VM is getting this error too but Postman Chrome App in my VM is not getting this error. What could be possibly go wrong? What can I check?