# angularjs malforms json while sending data to the server using POST

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express

I have a Nodejs express server and an angularJs client which sends data to the server.

The problem is when I try to send a JSON to the server with angularJS, the received JSON becomes like this:

```
{"{\"question\":\"What will be result of code int a ":" 5/2\",\"answers\":[{\"a\":\"2.50\",\"b\":\"1\",\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":\"no right answer\"}],\"answer\":\"c\",\"score\":\"100\"}"}
```

Here is my post method in angularJS:

```
createQuestion: function(question){
  delete question["_id"];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(question))
        return $http.post('http://localhost:3000/questions/', question, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    })
        .then(
                function(response){
                    return response.data;
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while creating question');
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
        );
    }
```

the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(question))` is:

```
{"question":"What will be result of code int a = 5/2","answers":[{"a":"2.50","b":"1","c":"2","d":"no right answer"}],"answer":"c","score":"100"}
```

Here is the part of the code in nodejs responsible for POST methods:

```
exports.create_a_question = function(req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
  var new_question = new Question(req.body);
  new_question.save(function(err, question) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(question);
  });
};
```

After a search I found out that this problem happens because of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the header of requests but I add this configuration to my nodejs server and the problem still persists:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Here is CORS headers on nodejs server:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Ag', '3600');
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you want to send json, why use `Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded`? Also, angularjs doesn't strongify your data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545072/angularjs-http-post-send-data-as-json

Comment: Try removing `headers` from the `$http.post` request.

Comment: @Andrew because using application/json returns 404 on angular https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-error-404-when-sending-data-with-http-post/9876

Comment: @31piy I did that, but I get 404 error https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-error-404-when-sending-data-with-http-post/9876

Comment: @I've updated my question, including headers

Comment: Possibly related:
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180001/getting-response-404-while-posting-json-payload-to-post-rest-api

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, the default content type is `application/json`. Avoid using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And avoid using `bodyParser.urlencoded`. POST that data from AngularJS in JSON form, and receive it in Node.js as JSON. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20677558)

Comment: I get 404 error when I remove `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from the angular side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved the problem:
download the `cors` library via npm:

```
npm install --save cors
```

use it in the code:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

then I removed the unnecessary header option when calling angularjs `$http.post`

Answer (score 0):

The back slashes (`"\"`) happen when `JSON.stringify` is called twice:

```js
var x = {a:1, b:2};
var y1 = JSON.stringify(x);
var y2 = JSON.stringify(y1);
console.log(y2);
```

The AngularJS framework automatically does a `JSON.stringify` with the `$http.post` method. The second `JSON.stringify` was called in the Node.js code.

The solution is to use `JSON.parse` in the Node.js code:

```js
var x = {a:1, b:2};
var y1 = JSON.stringify(x);
var y2 = JSON.parse(y1);
console.log(y2);
```

Comment: So I removed the unnecessary JSON.stringify from the angular when calling $http.post, and now I get the message in nodejs server as [Object object] and when I use JSON.parse(req.body) I get error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` and when I try to print an element of JSON with `console.log(req.body["question"])` I get undefined in the console

Answer (score -1):

Possibly:

```
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache'}
```

Since there are multiple content types at issue here ...

Comment: I still get 404